# django accessing foreignkey vlues of the model from another in shell

Tags: django, django-models

I have a django model as follows:

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    model1name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)

class Model2(models.Model):
    model1 = models.ForeignKey(Model1)
    model2name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
```

In the shell i am trying to access the values present in Model1 using the foreign key value of model2 but i am not sure how to get them.

What command should i use to get the values in the foreign key model?

I tried something like this but did not work:

```
item = Model2.objects.model1.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The foreign key is from a specific instance of model2, not the class itself. So assuming you have an instance, you can just follow the relationship with standard dot notation:

```
my_model2_instance.model1.model1name
```